# postgresql condition maximum value from five last record between each group id

Tags: sql, postgresql

I use this query for seperate last five record for each id

```sql
    select
        section_id,
        date,
        amount_a,
        amount_b,
        row_num
    from
        (
        select
            section_id,
            date,
            amount_a,
            amount_b,
            row_number() over (partition by section_id
        order by
            date desc) as row_num
        from
            amount
    ) t
    where
        row_num <= 10 
    order by
        section_id,date;
```

```
 section_id |      date    | amount_a | amount_b  | row_num
 -----------+--------------+----------+---------- +----------
      1     |   2021-08-01 | 9693.00  | 9523.00   |     1
      1     |   2021-08-02 | 9320.00  | 9341.00   |     2
      1     |   2021-08-03 | 9321.00  | 92245.00  |     3
      1     |   2021-08-04 | 9320.00  | 9412.00   |     4
      1     |   2021-08-05 | 9320.00  | 9325.00   |     5
      2     |   2021-08-01 | 45623.00 | 45550.00  |     1
      2     |   2021-08-02 | 47725.00 | 48500.00  |     2
      2     |   2021-08-03 | 49448.00 | 49787.00  |     3
      2     |   2021-08-04 | 48768.00 | 46251.00  |     4
      2     |   2021-08-05 | 49800.00 | 41254.00  |     5
      3     |   2021-08-01 | 623.00   | 854.00    |     1
      3     |   2021-08-02 | 725.00   | 698.00    |     2
      3     |   2021-08-03 | 448.00   | 524.00    |     3
      3     |   2021-08-04 | 768.00   | 784.00    |     4
      3     |   2021-08-05 | 800.00   | 850.00    |     5
```

I need to get an section_id if the following two conditions are met:

1-Is the last record the amount_a  maximum record among the 5 records?

2-In last record amount_a > amount_b?
In the above data, section_id 2 has both conditions,
49800 is greater between five related record and greater amount_b

Comment: `order by desc` <<-- order by *what* ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Revised:**  
The WINDOWED version of COUNT and MAX still satisfies.
What the last 5 requirement (from your last comment)  does is introduce another layer of filtering. You must first filter to just the last 5 rows. Then in the next step apply the MAX function. Finally the last step applies your 3 initial requirement. See [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=227b1c0930dd743602bf577ffc4ad745)

```
  select 
        section_id,
        dt,
        amount_a,
        amount_b, 
        a_max, 
        row_num         
    from
        (select f1.*
              , max(amount_a) over (partition by section_id) as a_max  
           from ( select
                      section_id,
                      dt,
                      amount_a,
                      amount_b,
                      row_number() over (partition by section_id
                                             order by dt  --desc
                                        ) as row_num,
                     -- max(amount_a) over (partition by section_id) as a_max, 
                      count(*)      over (partition by section_id) as s_count                   
                   from amount
               ) f1
         where row_num = s_count-5
       ) t
    where row_num >= s_count
        and amount_a  = a_max
        and amount_a > amount_b
    order by
        section_id,dt;
```

NOTE: Also change order by criteria on row_number from `order by date desc` to just `order by date` (so now ascending);

---

The aggregate functions MAX and COUNT also have a Windowed counterpart. You can add these to your existing sub query and extend the where on the main query: (see [example here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=bf2d384f5613d9b75259dfb8fbb14382))

```
   select 
        section_id,
        dt,
        amount_a,
        amount_b,
        row_num
    from
        (
          select
               section_id,
               dt,
               amount_a,
               amount_b,
               row_number() over (partition by section_id
                                      order by dt desc
                                 ) as row_num,
               max(amount_a) over (partition by section_id) as a_max, 
               count(*)      over (partition by section_id) as s_count                   
            from amount
         ) t
    where
        s_count = row_num        -- last record
        and amount_a  = a_max    -- 1. amount_a is max
        and amount_a > amount_b  -- 2. amount_a > amount_b
    order by
        section_id,dt;
```

**Caution:** You should not use DATE as a column name. It is a Postgres data type and (while not Postgres) a SQL Standard reserved word. While you get away with it now adds confusion and could potentially cause your queries to fail if Postgres follows the SQL Standard in a later release.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.I have a lot of data and I just want the calculations to be done on the last 5 records. [for example link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=2bb50424a319cc789b0bcda92bd7d3e5). The correct result should be this date:2021-08-05

Comment: See revised query.